# Proof by contradiction that the equation $x^2-y^2=2$ has no integer solution

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Use proof by contradiction to show that there is no integer solution of the equation $$x^2 -y^2 = 2$$
My turn:
Assume that the equation has at least one integer solution
, then $$a^2 = 2+b^2$$  such that a , b are integers, but $$a^2 = b^2 + 2b + 1 + 1-2b$$
$$a^2 = (b+1)^2 +1-2b$$ Since $a^2$ is integer but not perfect square , then $a$ is not integer which contradicts the assumption. Is this solution correct ?

Comment: How do you justify $(b+1)^2+1-2b$ cannot be a perfect square?

Comment: Hint for an alternative approach : Every square number is congruent to $0$ or $1$ modulo $4$

Answer (score 4):

Note that $2=(x-y)(x+y).$ If $x,y$ have the same parity, the RHS is divisible by $4,$ contradiction. If $x,y$ have different parity, then the RHS is odd, contradiction yet again.

Comment: Would you illustrate what does ''the same parity " means , because i did not understand the solution @Display name

Comment: @Hussien Mohamed Both even or both odd.

Comment: Thank you &Display name

Answer (score 0):

First we note that $(x+y)(x-y)=2$ and hence $x>y$. Further, one can see that $x \neq 0 $ and $y\neq 0$ must hold and we cannot have the case that $|x|=|y|=1$. Also, one bracket must equal $2$ and the other must equal $1$.

If we assume that $x,y$ are integers then it it follows $x>0$ and $y<0$. This leads to a contradiction because $(x+y)$ cannot equal $1$ where at the same time $(x-y)=2$. It is also impossible that $(x+y)=2$ and at the same time $(x-y)=1$.